# Python Named Capturing Groups and Backreferences Question

Tags: python, regex

I have this python regex

`\bP(?P<A>[!@#$%^&*()_+\-= ]){0,}A(?P=A){0,}J<(?P=A){0,}L(?P=A){0,}A(?P=A){0,}D(?P=A){0,}A\b`

Which matches `PAJLADA` and `P-A-J-L-A-D-A` without issue.

I wondered if I could use this same concept for matching of the characters in any order, or if there was something else I could use for that.

as per example

`P-A#J!L-A^D&A`

Comment: You need a recursion/subroutine support, so you need to use Python PyPi `regex` module and use constructs like `(?&A)`.

Comment: See https://rextester.com/DRFW25082

Comment: With a regex this simple, just repeat the token, or construct the regex with string concatenation.